# When I try to add a schema in stackmob it is not getting saved

Tags: stackmob

I was trying to do a tutorial in stackmob but while I try to save a schema and when I come back to it I cant find the changes I made to the schema?Any help??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean that you are in the Stackmob Dashboard and trying to create and save a schema, there are two snags that can get you (and me).  If you didn't hit save schema, nothing will be saved.  The other snag can be that you do not set the Create, Read, Update, and Delete permissions at the bottom of the page, although I think it flags this as something you must complete.  If these things have been done and your data is not being retained, provide a bit more info and I can try my best to help.

Comment: When i do this the first time i got it correctly. But after that the next day when i tried the schema is not there and cant be saved. I was trying to do their android tutorial snapshare.